# Is it possible to set breakpoint in Eclipse in java.lang.Thread.run method?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, breakpoints

I need to track where is thread that in Eclipse debugger seen as:

```
Warning-123
```

is created.
Is it possible to set a breakpoint in Eclipse in java.lang.Thread.run method? How to filter out only this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. As far as breaking on only "this" thread, you probably need to add a conditional checking the thread name and put the break in the conditional.